3D spider pathfinding
I stumbled upon a difficult problem..
I have created procedurally animated spider-like creature, and I need to bring him to life with path finding.
Issue is that it has some very specific requirements:

I dont want to move with spider just on ground, it would be much cooler if it could walk on walls and ceilings.
Spiders can't float so it has to be within some specified distance from objects (too far and spider will levitate, too close and spider will be squished on wall and look bad)

I wasnt able to find any implementation of such pathfinding, tried to make some custom voxel octree generation, but I couldnt make it to work with object distance restrictions. Every solution i tried wasnt able to satisfy distance requirements or wasnt scalable past small tests.
Specifically I want to solve it in Unity but any explenation or code samples are appreciated. It doesent have to be fast to generate because it will be done just once before build, but it has to be fast to pathfind through, and as memory efficient as possible (even few hours of generating the graph for entire scene is good enough for my usage).

navmeshes should work fine for vertical or inverted surfaces, but I have not used Unity so I can't tell if the built in will work, I would suspect that at least some of the tooling might not be usable.

I dont think NavMesh can solve this, it was intended for 2d use and even if i would create multiple of them Id still need to somehow jump between them in correct places but maybe someone will prove me wrong

Why would a navmesh not work? It is just a simplified mesh used to generate a graph for use with A*. The implementation provided by Unity might not work, but you could always build your own navmesh implementation and tooling.

As I said I want spider to be able to walk on walls ceilings, random pilars inside a room uneven surfaces and vary y offset (propendicular to mesh currently standing on)

Yes? meshes can be in 3D, I considered that fairly obvious. It might be a lot of work to create a connected and continuous mesh from the render geometry, but once that is done the pathfinding should be fairly straightforward. I think you are mistaking unitys assumption that navmeshes are horizontal for an inherent limitation.

From my understanding Nav mesh cant do one thing, lets imagine two pilars in a room with spider on one of them. Navmesh thinks of the pilars like disconected surfaces, so spider has to go down on flor connecting those pillars and go back up. If the spider has some reach for example one meter, it can just step between those pilars. I want volume-like movement. Yes I could connect the pilar with connections that nav meshes have in unity but that would restrict the spider just with limited number of points that I provided

you can have multiple meshes, and you can have links between them

Yes I coul,d thats also valid solution, but with limited nuber of links the movement wont feel as fluid as with full volume path finding...

Maybe I should just reduce my expectations?

@PHOENIX33201 I guess you could implement your own A* algorithm by placing points all over the 3d meshes that act as possible locations to move to?

@robotrage that basicly what navMesh implements, I tried something similar, instead of placing it just on meshes I placed them everywhere (within some boundary) measured their distance from nearest collider. That distances were used as radiuses for spheres. Than checked adjacend spheres, If they collided they were added to graph as connected. Because its based on spheres I can easily check for distance requirements. It has two major drawbacks tho, It is not scalable for good resolution of graph You need milions of spheres, and second its time complexity is O(sphere count * triangle count)

@PHOENIX33201 why use spheres and collider's instead of simply using an array of vectors x, y & checking their distance in space instead of physics colliders
